# Passing dictionary as parameter to a function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

So, I am working on a project in which the user gives inputs in the json file and the parser reads data from the json file and then creates a data structure to which gets updated to the inputs mentioned in the data file.

My json file(input_file.json5) looks like this:

```
     {
        "clock_frequency": 25000,
        "Triggering_Mode": "positive_edge_triggered",
        "Mode": "Offline",
        "overshoot": 0.05,
        "duty_cycle": 0.5,
        "amplitude/high_level": 1,
        "offset/low_level": 0
     }
```

The data structure(data_struc.py) looks like this:

```py
Parameters={
    "Global_parameters": {
        "frequency": 3000,
        "Triggering_Mode": "positive_edge_triggered"
    },
    "Executor_param": {
        "Mode": "Offline"
    },
    "Waveform_Settings": {
        "overshoot": 0.05,
        "duty_cycle": 0.5,
        "amplitude/high_level": 1,
        "offset/low_level": 0,
    }
}
```

The code for the parser is:

```
import json5
from data_struc import Parameters

class Parser(object):

    def read_input_file(self, path_name, file_name):
         input_file = open(path_name + file_name + '.json5')
         data = json5.load(input_file)
         print(Parameters['Global_parameters'])
         parameters = self.parse_parameters(data)
         input_file.close()
         return parameters

   def parser_parameters(self, data):
         parameter = {
               "Global_parameters": {
                                        "frequency": data[clock_frequency]
                                        "Triggering_Mode": data[Triggering_Mode]
                                    }
                     }
         return parameter
```

I want to pass data as a parameter to the function and I want to update the contents of the data structure using the value of the data(passed as dictionary) to the function. How do I implement the function parser_parameters?

Comment: To be clear: when you call `parser_parameters`, you want the contents of the imported `Parameters` dict to be updated, using values that came from the passed-in `data`? Well, do you know how to modify the content of a dictionary? Do you know which parts should be modified?

Comment: Also, what is the `5` for in your custom `.json5` extension? o_O You can of course name your files what you want, but it might cause problems for other tools.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel  Yes, I want the contents of the imported Parameters dict to be updated, using values that came from the passed-in data. I want to modify all the contents of the Parameters as per data.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel json5 is the superset of json. In this project I also have a module named the main_moddule which takes the path and name of the json file from the user.

Comment: Okay, so for example, you want the value of `Parameters['Global_Parameters']['frequency']` to become equal to the value of `data['clock_frequency']`? I think you know how to do this...

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. I could have done this directly but I want to pass this data as a parameter to the function and I also want to return parameter as a dictionary so that I can use it in other modules.

Comment: Could you please suggest a way how to pass the dictionary as a parameter to a function and use it to modify other dictionary.

Comment: You "pass a dictionary as a parameter to the function"... the same way you pass anything else, which is the way that you already show in your code above: you want a parameter named `data`, so you include it in the parameter list, and then you write code that makes use of the `data` assuming it's a dictionary. - Wait, are you confused about how to **call** the method? In that case, could you show the code where you create the `Parser` instance and try to use it?

Comment: from parser_file import Parser
  def main():
            path= input("Enter the path name:")
            name= input("Enter the name of the file:")
            parser=Parser()
            parameter= parser.read_input_file(path,name)
            print (parameter)
main()

Comment: The way I have passed the data as a parameter in the code is not working. I'm getting error.

Comment: Oh, wait, I see. You want your outside code to call `read_input_file`, and then *that* will call `parser_parameters`? Then you simply have a typo, and need to read the error message as well as your code more closely: `parse_parameters` and `parser_parameters` are not the same.

Comment: I tried after changing it to parser_parameters, it is not working yet

Comment: There is some error in the "parser_parameters" function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a one-liner to map the data to a schema if you can change the schema, you could also just go and grab the keys instead of creating a list of items to match. This formats the data to the schema based on matching keys:

EDIT: added 'Data' tag to the schema and output for nested list data

```py
schema = {
    'Global_parameters': [
        'clock_frequency', # I noticed you had this as just 'clock' in your desired outuput
        'Triggering_Mode'
    ],
    'Executor_param': [
        'Mode'
    ],
    'Waveform_Settings': [
        'overshoot',
        'duty_cycle',
        'amplitude/high_level',
        'offset/low_level'
    ],
    'Data': {
        'Packet'
    }
}

data = {
    "clock_frequency": 25000,
    "Triggering_Mode": "positive_edge_triggered",
    "Mode": "Offline",
    "overshoot": 0.05,
    "duty_cycle": 0.5,
    "amplitude/high_level": 1,
    "offset/low_level": 0,
    "Packet": [
        {"time_index":0.1, "data":0x110},
        {"time_index":1.21, "data":123},
        {"time_index":2.0, "data": 0x45}
    ]
}

# "one line" nested dict comprehension
data_structured = {k0: {k1: v1 for k1, v1 in data.items() if k1 in v0} # in v0.keys() if you are using the structure you have above
                   for k0, v0 in schema.items()}

import json
print(json.dumps(data_structured, indent=4)) # pretty print in json format
```

Output:

```py
{
    "Global_parameters": {
        "clock_frequency": 25000,
        "Triggering_Mode": "positive_edge_triggered"
    },
    "Executor_param": {
        "Mode": "Offline"
    },
    "Waveform_Settings": {
        "overshoot": 0.05,
        "duty_cycle": 0.5,
        "amplitude/high_level": 1,
        "offset/low_level": 0
    },
    "Data": {
        "Packet": [
            {
                "time_index": 0.1,
                "data": 272
            },
            {
                "time_index": 1.21,
                "data": 123
            },
            {
                "time_index": 2.0,
                "data": 69
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I have one more query. In the data I have one more item which is                     
 "Packet": [
    {
      "time_index":0.1,
      "data":0x110
    },
    {
      "time_index":1.21,
      "data":123
    },
    {
      "time_index":2.0,
      "data": 0x45
    }
  ],                                 and in my data structure I have an item as  "Packet": {
        "time_index": [],
        "data_value": []
    },        I want to read the contents of Packets and save it in data structure. Could you please tell how should I continue?

Comment: that makes it a bit more complex but it is still possible to add another key/value to the schema but the simple way may not give you what you want for the nested list, I will update with the simple way and you can let me know if it works